# Translate dynamic text in magento 2 javascript

Tags: magento2.4, knockoutjs

i have a text like **within %1 days** %1 is dynamic how to translate using data-bind:i18n in html template magento 2.4

```
<span data-bind="text:methoddata[key].delivery_days_text"></span>
```

any one modify this

Answer (score 0):

To translate a dynamic string like "within %1 days" using data-bind:i18n in Magento 2.4, you can follow these steps:

1. Update the string in your HTML template to include a placeholder for the dynamic value using %1, like this:

2. In your JavaScript file, define a variable for the dynamic value and replace the placeholder in the translated string using sprintf function. For example:

   ```
   var deliveryDays = 5; // Or get the value dynamically from your data source
   var deliveryDaysText = $.mage.__('within %1 days').replace('%1', deliveryDays);
   methoddata[key].delivery_days_text = deliveryDaysText;
   ```
3. Finally, update the text binding in your HTML template to use the translated and formatted value, like this:

This should output a translated string with the dynamic value included, like "within 5 days". Make sure to replace "methoddata[key]" with the actual path to your data object in the JavaScript code.

Comment: in inline cant replace?

Comment: methoddata[key].delivery_days_text  this data having 5 (days)

Comment: Try like this:
<span data-bind="i18n: 'within %1 days', attr: { title: $t('within %1 days', {'days': methoddata[key].delivery_days_text}) }"></span>

Comment: not worked text translated but %1 is not changed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using

https://github.com/willwright/Mecodeninja_DynamicTranslation

This would include the translation that is marked as dynamic in the js-transation.json for runtime translating variables and is very viable with the minimum overhead of code.